# Regex to optionally match 3 digits at the end of file name

Tags: c#, regex

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get these to match:

```
File name without 3 digit end.jpg
File name with 3 digit 123.gif
Single 123.jpg
Single.png
```

But not these:

```
Single 1.jpg
Single 123b.gif
More words 123b.png
```

The best I could so so far is this expression:

```
^[^\s]((?!\s{2})(?!,\S).)*\b(\p{L}+|\d{3})\.\w{3}$
```

But it fails to match `Single.png` and still matches `Single 123b.gif` and `More words 123b.png`.
I think I understand why it doesn't work but I can't figure out how to get it right, and I have been struggling and Googling for 2 days.

My full rules are: optionally exactly 3 digits at the end before the file extension, 3 letter file extension, no double spaces in the file name and a single space after but not before a comma.

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference between `these` and `not these`.

Comment: @sln The file name should end (before the extension) with a number of exactly 3 digits or no number at all. So not a number less or more than 3 digits are a number with a letter attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take your requiremenet into account about the comma and the double spaces, one option could be to use 2 negative lookaheads to assert that the string does not contain a double space and does not contain a space before the comma.

You could use `\s` if you want to match a whitespace character instead of a single space.

```
^(?!.*[ ]{2})(?!.* ,).*\b(?:\p{L}+|\d{3})\.\w{3}$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!.*[ ]{2})` Assert not 2 spaces
- `(?!.* ,)` Assert not a single space and a comma
- `.*\b` Match any char 0+ times followed by a word boundary
- `(?:\p{L}+|\d{3})` Either match 1+ times a letter or 3 digits
- `\.\w{3}` Match `.` and 3 word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hIzTf/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/MezZQ0)

Comment: This is perfect and even a bit clearer now why it works. Thank you!

Comment: I did find a small error in that the above also matches strings that have neither a number or letter in the final word, like `Single %123.jpg` and `Single [123].jpg`.
Why is this? The expression says: either 1+ times a letter OR 3 digits and nothing else, right?

Comment: @Mytzenka Yes that is because the `.*` is greedy and matches first until the end and then it backtracks fulllfill the rest of the pattern. The requirement stated `optionally exactly 3 digits at the end before the file extension` so it does not match 1 or 2 digits before the file extension. What are the allowed characters for the filename? I don't think it matches `Single [123]` see [test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5b+%5d%7b2%7d%29%28%3f!.*+%2c%29.*%5cb%28%3f%3a%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%7c%5cd%7b3%7d%29%5c.%5cw%7b3%7d%24&i=Single+%5b123%5d.jpg)

Comment: I would like to allow basically all characters that are normally allowed in the file name, but I could just say letters, numbers and `,_-;[]()` If the last word is a number than it must be exactly 3 digits without any letters or other special characters.

Comment: @Mytzenka You could use a character class and specify the allowed charcters https://regex101.com/r/SQhNWY/1 like https://ideone.com/vkhNHf

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternation group that includes either 3 digits or a sequence of non-digits, preceded by a word boundary assertion:

```
^.*?\b(?:\d{3}|\D+)\.\w{3}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/A9iSVE/3

Answer (score 0):

You can meet the specified rules without backtracking (which the currently accepted answer does). The rules specified are (rephrased for clarity): A filename MUST meet the following conditions:

- It MUST NOT contain a sequence of multiple space characters.
- A comma MUST have exactly one space character following it.
- The filename stem MAY have a 3-digit suffix.
- The filename extension MUST consist of 3 letters.

To that end:

```
^(?<prefix>[^, ]+(,? [^, ]+)*)(?<suffix>\d\d\d)?(?<extension>.\p{L}\p{L}\p{L})$
```

will do the trick, no fancy lookahead, no backtracking. Broken out into its pieces, you get:

```
^                  # * match start-of-text, followed by
(?<prefix>         # * a named group, consisting of
  [^,\x20]+        #   * 1 or more characters other than comma or space, followed by
  (                #   * a group, consisting of
    ,?             #     * an optional comma, followed by
    \x20           #     * a single space character, followed by
    [^,\x20]+      #     * 1 or more characters other than comma or space
  )*               #     with the whole group repeated zero or more times
)                  #   followed by
(?<suffix>         # * an optional named group (the suffix), consisting of
  \d\d\d           #   * 3 decimal digits
)?                 #   followed by
(?<extension>      # * a mandatory named group (the filename extension), consisting of
  .\p{L}\p{L}\p{L} #   * 3 letters.
)                  #   followed by
$                  # end-of-text
```